# Position an element in the middle of header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make it work in firefox? I want `p` element to be positioned vertically in the middle of `header`.

`header` need to stay absolute positioned

http://jsfiddle.net/a65tr/

**html**

```
<header>
<p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
</header>
```

**css**

```
header {
    color: #3B4043;
    font-family: 'source_sans_prolight',sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    height: 234px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}

header p {
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-table;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vertical-align` to center it and delete the position of `p` tag and the problem will be solved !

---

### [DEMO : jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a65tr/1/)

Try this css code here :

```
header {
    color: #3B4043;
    font-family: 'source_sans_prolight',sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    height: 234px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    display:table;
}

header p {
    bottom: 0;
display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: @user2537093 Your welcome dear friend ;) you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the line height the same as the height

```
header p {
    line-height: 234px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a65tr/3/*

**I removed some styling that wasn't needed to clear things up a bit. the `left:0;right0;` is not needed when you have `width:100%`, one is enough*

Comment: It will break if the text has more than one line.

Comment: Yes, but it's a header, it might be just 1 line. Just providing alternative solutions

Comment: Thank you for this alternative ;)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way for youger browser is :

```
header {
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
text-align:center;
height:250px;
}
header p {
margin:auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a65tr/5/)** *http://jsfiddle.net/a65tr/6/ in absolute*

---

Or http://jsfiddle.net/a65tr/7/

```
<!--language:css-->
header {
display:table;
width:100%;
height:250px;
text-align:center;
}
header p {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative ;)

Comment: you are welcome, always good to know a few ways, it helps to choose for a good reason :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
header p{
 width:100%;
 margin-top:auto;
 margin-bottom:auto;
}
```

Comment: The question was vertical, not horizontal :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot :)